# XAMPP MySQL shutdowns

Tags: php, mysql

6:26:53 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.

6:26:53 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,

6:26:53 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

6:26:53 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check

6:26:53 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues

6:26:53 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this

6:26:53 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums

**mysql_error.txt:**

[image]

WEV(?):

[image]

EDIT: Fixed thanks to reinstall.

Comment: > _Press the Logs button to view error logs and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues_

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be about programming.

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that something is using the same ports that your trying to run MYSQL on check to see what port its trying to connect to and change it to something free try using port 8001 or something.

Before this maybe try closing a few programs down first or even restarting before trying again! It could be any program you have installed and running in the background because generally the mysql ports should be free

For me Skype was using one of the prots that xampp was trying to use so it constantly failed.

Comment: Tried to change port from the my.ini. No progress. I have 0 programs running in background. I am pretty new to coding and stuff ...